# Select into memory optimised table

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-sql, sql-server-2016, memory-optimized-tables

I have a stored procedure that will convert some dynamic sql into either a temp table or view dependant on a database setting.  This is used to "tune" database functionality between different clients depending on size of data, i.e. temp table takes longer to create but takes longer to setup, a view creates quickly but takes slightly longer to read.

I am looking at expanding this out to include an option for memory optimised tables but can't see how to use a memory optimised table without declaring it fully first.

My code at the moment would be of a format like:

```
SELECT TOP 10 *
INTO FavoriteCustomers
FROM Customers
ORDER BY Spend DESC
```

As you can see I'm not declaring the table, just using select into.  Is there any way I can SELECT INTO a memory optimised table?  I can use:

```
sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set(@mySQLhere)
```

Which gives me a column definition for the TSQL I pass in. Then use this info to pre-build the table and insert into it, but I'm hoping for a neater method if possible.

Does anyone have any solutions? Search just takes me down the road of how to add data to a MOT not MOT creation as part of a select.

I understand this may not be possible, and I do have the work around described, I just feel I may be missing a better option here.

Currently using multiple servers, MOT functions only being implemented on SQL2016.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I was looking into something similar to try and force the execution of a query in a certain order without losing performance. I think they would have mentioned such a solution in this article about replacing temp tables with memory optimized tables if it existed: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/in-memory-oltp/faster-temp-table-and-table-variable-by-using-memory-optimization

Comment: I never did find a nice work around for this.  I ended up creating the table first, then using a standard insert into query. It works fine.  I'll post my code as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE PROC [engine].[usp_CreateDynamicContent]
    @ContentName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
,   @NTS_SessionID NVARCHAR(MAX)
,   @SelectSQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
,   @PrimaryKeyField NVARCHAR(MAX) = NULL
,   @NonClusteredIndexField NVARCHAR(MAX) = NULL
,   @debug BIT = 0
AS
    BEGIN

        DECLARE @ContentType AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
        DECLARE @dcName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
        DECLARE @strSQL AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

        SET @dcName = 'tmp.dc_' + @ContentName + '_' + @NTS_SessionID

        IF OBJECT_ID(@dcName, 'V') IS NOT NULL /* Drop the view if it exists */
            BEGIN
                SET @strSQL = 'DROP VIEW ' + @dcName
                IF @debug = 1
                    PRINT (@strSQL)
                EXEC (@strSQL)
            END

        IF OBJECT_ID(@dcName) IS NOT NULL /* Drop the table if it exists */
            BEGIN
                SET @strSQL = 'DROP TABLE ' + @dcName
                IF @debug = 1
                    PRINT (@strSQL)
                EXEC (@strSQL)
            END

        /* This is my database listing types for each table. */
        SELECT  @ContentType = ContentType
        FROM    guid.DynamicContents
        WHERE   ContentName = @ContentName

        IF @ContentType = 'VIEW'
            BEGIN
                SET @strSQL = 'CREATE VIEW ' + @dcName + ' AS' + CHAR(13) + @SelectSQL
                IF @debug = 1
                    PRINT (@strSQL)
                EXEC (@strSQL)
            END
        ELSE
            IF @ContentType IN ('TABLE', 'MOT')
                BEGIN
                    SET @strSQL = ''
                    SELECT  @strSQL = @strSQL + ',' + CHAR(10) + '[' + name + '] ' + system_type_name + CASE WHEN @PrimaryKeyField IS NOT NULL
                                                                                                                  AND @ContentType = 'MOT' THEN ' NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED'
                                                                                                             ELSE ''
                                                                                                        END + CHAR(13)
                    FROM    sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set(@SelectSQL, NULL, 0)
                    SET @strSQL = STUFF(@strSQL, 1, 1, 'CREATE TABLE ' + @dcName + '(')

                    IF @PrimaryKeyField IS NOT NULL
                        AND @ContentType = 'TABLE'
                        BEGIN
                            SET @strSQL = @strSQL + CHAR(10) + ',CONSTRAINT pk_' + @ContentName + '_' + @NTS_SessionID + ' PRIMARY KEY (' + @PrimaryKeyField + ')' + CHAR(10)
                        END

                    SET @strSQL = @strSQL + ')'
                    IF @debug = 1
                        PRINT (@strSQL)
                    EXEC (@strSQL)

                    IF @NonClusteredIndexField IS NOT NULL
                        AND @ContentType = 'TABLE'
                        BEGIN
                            SET @strSQL = 'CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ix_' + @ContentName + '_' + @NonClusteredIndexField + ' ON ' + @dcName + ' (' + @NonClusteredIndexField + ')'
                            IF @debug = 1
                                PRINT (@strSQL)
                            EXEC (@strSQL)
                        END

                    /* This section added in as I use cte's quite a lot */
                    IF @SelectSQL LIKE '%/* INSERT HERE */%'
                        BEGIN
                            SET @strSQL = REPLACE(@SelectSQL, '/* INSERT HERE */', 'INSERT INTO ' + @dcName)
                        END
                    ELSE
                        BEGIN
                            SET @strSQL = 'INSERT INTO ' + @dcName + CHAR(13) + @SelectSQL 
                        END
                    IF @debug = 1
                        PRINT (@strSQL)
                    EXEC (@strSQL)
                END

    END
```

Comment: add explanation please